# Is it correct to convert $\;a + b < c\;$ to $\;c - a > b\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Will it be correct if I convert $a + b < c$ to $c - a > b$?
>
> Will they mean the same thing?

I am just a bit confused with the $<$ operator. If it were $=$ I would be confident about it, because $a + b = c \implies b = c - a$.

Comment: What about $<$ confuses you? For clarity, all it means is “one quantity is less than another quantity” (so one mental picture that might help you understand is imagining a scale with a bucket on either end...one side is definitely heavier than the other).

Comment: I would call $<$ a relation rather than an operator

Answer (score 2):

$$a+b<c$$

You can subtract $a$ from both sides, to get:

$$b<c-a$$

You can now swap both sides, but also flipping the inequality the opposite way (if one thing is smaller than another, that other thing is greater than the first):

$$c-a>b$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Jaap, another alternative way of doing it is

$$a + b < c$$ converts to $$a < c - b$$ after decreasing both sides by $b$. After this, we subtract both sides by $c$ to get $$a - c < -b$$So, after multiplying both sides by $-1$, we get $\boxed{c - a > b}$.